# Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function in Wordpress Theme

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, wordpress

I'm planning to use jQuery autocomplete combo in theme. Loaded script files as follow in header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

When I try it I got javascript error as **Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function**. This is jquery ui autocomplete [demo](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)  and I try it at JSFiddle also worked as demo. That's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmzaw/2k0ftw8x/7/) working demo. I got **$.widget** error When I add it in wordpress theme. How can I fix it

Comment: you should use wordpress' enqueue script functions to ensure the scripts etc are loaded in the right (dependency!) order.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call jquery ui widget in theme's functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
```

Comment: Try it before and don't get javascript error but it doesn't work. So I decided to call with above style and got error

Comment: try to use 'jQuery' variable instead of '$' , as jquery in wordpress  is loaded in no-conflict mode

Comment: According to the this tutorial http://devotepress.com/tutorials-hacks/wordpress-coding/how-to-properly-use-jquery-scripts-in-wordpress/ I'm using Proper way and get **$.widget** is not a function. When I try to replace _$_ with _jQuery_ i got _jQuery.widget_ is not a function. Any other way to fix it?

Comment: When I try with this method
`/*!
 * Coding jQuery Proper Way
 * using wrapper 
 * to be executed after the document has been loaded
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});`  I didn't get any error But I think $.widget function didn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still getting this error I solved this error by installing this plugin for wordpress.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-ui-widgets/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).